# Graphql Close Bracket Location

Tags: graphql

I am getting a syntax error for my GraphQL API and I have no clue why it is happening.  The error log gives me no location of this syntax error.  I have looked through all of the schemas and they all have closing brackets.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\error\syntaxError.js:24
  return new _GraphQLError.GraphQLError("Syntax Error: ".concat(description), undefined, source, [position]);
         ^
Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

GraphQL request (53:1)
52:
53: }
    ^
54:

    at syntaxError (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\error\syntaxError.js:24:10)
    at expect (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1463:32)
    at parseName (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:96:15)
    at parseInputValueDef (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:920:14)
    at many (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1520:16)
    at parseInputFieldsDefinition (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1083:50)
    at parseInputObjectTypeDefinition (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1067:16)
    at parseTypeSystemDefinition (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:736:16)
    at parseDefinition (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:142:16)
    at many (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1523:16)
    at parseDocument (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:113:18)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:48:10)
    at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql-tools\src\generate\buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.ts:37:19)
    at Object.makeExecutableSchema (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\graphql-tools\src\makeExecutableSchema.ts:52:18)
    at new ApolloServerBase (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\apollo-server-core\src\ApolloServer.ts:195:21)
    at new ApolloServer (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\apollo-server-express\src\ApolloServer.ts:68:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\src\app.ts:31:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PayMe\api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! type@1.0.0 start: `ts-node ./src/app.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the type@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-04T21_23_11_333Z-debug.log
```

User Schema:

```
type User {
  id: Int!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  avatar: String
  accessToken: String
  itemID: String
  jwt: String @isAuthUser
  groups: [Group]
}

input UserInput {
    email: String
    password: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    avatar: String
    accessToken: String
    itemID: String
}

type Query {
   getUser: User @isAuth
   loginUser(email: String!, password: String!): User
   logoutUser(email: String!): Boolean
}

type Mutation {
   createUser(data: UserInput): User
   updateAccessToken(accessToken: String): User @isAuth
}
```

Group Schema:

```
type Group {
  groupID: Int!
  name: String!
  description: String
  avatar: String

}

input GroupInput {
  name: String
  description: String
  avatar: String
  userID: String
}

type Query {
   groups: [Group]
   getGroup(groupID: Int!): Group @isAuth
   getUserGroups(userID: Int!): [Group] @isAuth

}

type Mutation {
  createGroup(data: GroupInput): Group @isAuth
  addMemberToGroup(userID: Int!, groupID: Int!): Group @isAuth
}
```

MemberOf Schema:

```
type MemberOf {
  id: Int!
  groupID: Int
  userID: Int
  isOwner: boolean
  isAdmin: boolean
}

type Query {

}

type Mutation {

}
```

I am not sure what order these schemas are compiled in.  This used to compile and run before I tried making a relationship between Group and User.  I have added the @BelongsToMany to User and Group and @ForiegnKey to the MemberOf.

Comment: Without actually including your schema, it's impossible for someone to tell you what the problem is. I can tell you 1) it's not a missing bracket, but a bracket where a [name](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#Name) is expected which *usually* means you missed some keyword; and 2) the error is on line 53 of your schema. If you have multiple schema files you are combining, you'll need to figure out the order in which they are combined in order to determine the location.

Comment: How do I figure out the order of which my multiple schema files are being combine?@DanielRearden

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Curly brackets serve three purposes in a GraphQL document. In executable documents, they identify a selection set, or a set of fields being requested. In type definitions, they either identify a set of fields (for an object type, an input object type or an interface) or they identify a set of values for an enum. **In all three cases,** the provided set cannot be empty. That is to say, **if** you use curly brackets, you **must** provide at least one item inside them.

An empty pair of curly brackets (`{}`) will always provide a syntax error.

If you don't need to provide a selection set/set of fields/set of enum values, just omit the curly brackets:

```
# Invalid
type Query {
}

# Valid (at least syntactically)
type Query
```